# Add files to private directory?

Tags: files, wysiwyg

I have set my "Private file system path" for uploaded private files (`admin/config/media/file-system`), but I am confused as to how to add any files to that directory. I expected to find a private files section in CKFinder.

How do I move files into the private directory?

Comment: Have you read https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/file#access ? Also, it looks like you encountered [known bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/1259510) or some mutation of it - it supposedly was fixed, though. But this area caused problems in the past so it wouldn't be surprise if it caused new ones.

Comment: @Mołot Ah... so after reading the link above, the private files location is only for files uploaded from a File field? Well, I tried that and it still doesn't put anything in that private directory.

Comment: not only, but file field is the main thing that support it. If it's configured to use private  filesystem, and it doesn't, something bad is happening. Can you post screenshots of your configurations?